# Creating a template with a title page, table of contents, then abstract

Tags: table-of-contents, abstract, apa6

Okay, so here's my issue- I am using `\documentclass{apa6}` in order to set up a template, but I am attempting to have the title page first, followed by the table of contents, and then the abstract, then the rest of the document. Currently, I can only seem to get the order to be title page, abstract, then table of contents. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass[12pt,man]{apa6}

\title{full title here}
\shorttitle{shorter title}
\author{by me}
\affiliation{insert affiliation here}
\date{\today}

\abstract{Abstract...}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1.5in,rmargin=1in}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\pagenumbering{arabic}
Intro here

\end{document}
```

Any help/advice would be much welcomed.

Comment: Welcome! Don't use a base class which imposes a very specific style on your document if you do not want your document to have that very specific style. Start with a more flexible, generic class and take any parts you want from the more specific one. Classes provided for typesetting articles for journals etc. are designed to stop you deviating from the house style. Of course, you *can* deviate, but the class makes it harder. This is what you want for compliance with a style required for submission. It isn't what you want when it isn't what you want.

Comment: In this case, `\maketitle` typesets the abstract. To change it, you have to redefine or patch the definition of `\maketitle`. But it will be much easier to build whatever format you want by starting from a more flexible base.

Comment: I wish upvote first cfr comment ten times more. Said that, you can simply omit  `\abstract{Abstract...}` in the preamble and make your own (fake) abstract section in the document.  Some like  `\tableofcontents\section*{\normalfont Abstract}\noindent  Abstract ... \section{Introduction} Intro here ...`  seems enough (... If you are not thinking in submit it to a journal requiring `apa6`).

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved easily by changing the apa6.cls file slightly. You will need to find the file first. On my linux system (arch) it is located at /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/apa6/apa6.cls

Now copy the file to your project directory (do not change the original apa6.cls file) and open it.

On line 1236 you see:

```
\newpage
%BDB\hyphenpenalty 10000
\fussy
```

And then the abstract definition starts:

```
\@ifundefined{@abstract}{}{%
  \section{\normalfont\normalsize\abstractname}% BDB
```

We will simply put \tableofcontents and \newpage before that, resulting in:

```
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
%BDB\hyphenpenalty 10000
\fussy
```

Here is a link to sharelatex to show the result: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/59d5123b8e70fc7b98c77198

You can also just download the apa6.cls from this project, put it in your working directory and it should work just fine.

Comment: I agree, edited it.