# How to "\vspace" in the titlepage in a apa6 class?

Tags: titles, apa6

It's my first time to use `apa6` class. I want to use the `[man]` option, but I found that the vertical space between title and author name was too large. Also the `\vspace` between author and affiliation is too small. I tried to put a `\vspace` command but it didn't work since it was in the title page, I thought. Then how to change the spaces flexibly?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Isn't APA just interested in the text? The template serves as a guide,, but it doesn't represent the final product.

Answer (score 0):

A related question: [Creating a template with a title page, table of contents, then abstract](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350474/creating-a-template-with-a-title-page-table-of-contents-then-abstract/394556#394556)

The basic idea is to make your own copy of the apa6.cls file (just copy the original one, either from your local install or from the ctan webpage, then put it in the folder where you have your .tex file). Search for the definitions of author and affiliation and change them accordingly. For my locally installed version the title is used on line 1591 and then come the authors and affiliations. For instance if there is a single author:

```
...
      \@ifundefined{@authorTwo}{
    % one author-affiliation
      {\Large \@author} \\

      \@affil \vspace{0.1in} \\ }{
...
```

Now, I assume you would just need to change (or add) the `vspace` here to achieve what you want.